# how to make a shortcut at toolbar in lyx?

Tags: lyx

I'm sorry my english is bad.
how to add a shorcut at toolbar in lyx??
so that If I klick the shorcut, I can connect to the TortoiseSVN,
just shorcut(seemlessly)
thanks.

Comment: pleae,anyone would help me? I need it for my graduate. thanks for help.

Answer (score 5):

This turns out not to be straight-forward at all. You need to do two things: create a new LyX command, and then create new menu item where you want it to appear.

First, some pointers:

LyX user interface and command files are stored in the `ui` and `commands` directories in:

- `~/.lyx` on Linux
- `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\LyX16\Resources` on Windows.

These settings are per-user, and it's generally not recommended to mess with the global settings. For reference, the equivalent global settings directories are in:

- `/usr/share/lyx` on Linux (might be different depending on your distribution)
- `%PROGRAMFILES%\Lyx16` on Windows.

---

What you need to do:

1. Define a new command in your per-user `commands` directory in a file `default.def` (create it if it doesn't exist, including the `commands` directory). Your command will look something like:

   ```
   \define "my-command" "vc-command <flags> \"path-to-command\" \"command-to-run\""
   ```

   - Note that you need to escape double quotes within the command definition as they delimit LyX commands and their arguments.
   - The `<flags>` can be one or more of `UDIRM` (no flags, need loaded document, mark document "dirty", reload after execution, ask for user input). Combine as needed.
   - Within `path-to-command` you might use `$$p` to denote the current document path, and in `command-to-run` you can additionally use `$$i` and `$$m` which will be substituted with the current document or message, respectively. For the full syntax, you might want to look at `LFUN.lyx` at the `doc` directory in your installation, or choose *Help->LyX functions* from the program itself.

   In your case, you will probably have something like:

   ```
   \define "svn-commit" "vc-command D \"path-to-svn.exe\" \"svn commit %%i\""
   ```
2. With the command done, you will need to create a menu item for it in the interface. You 
   can choose between menu items, toolbar items and context menus. Full treatment of the syntax will take a lot of space here, so I defer you to take a look at `stdtoolbars.inc`, `stdmenus.inc`, `stdcontext.inc` to see how the syntax looks like. Something that should work for you:

   - Copy the `default.ui` file from the global `ui` directory to the local one.
   - Create a new "mymenu.ui`file in the local`ui` directory. In it, you'll have something like: 
         Toolbar "my-toolbar" "My toolbar"
              Item "SVN Commit" "svn-commit"
              ...
         End

   Check one of the `stdtoolbars.inc` file in the global `ui` directory to see how the syntax looks like.

   - Edit your local `default.ui` and add the following line below the other includes:

     ```
     Include "mymenu.ui"
     ```

     Further down, add your toolbar in the `Toolbars` section somewhere. The file has in-line instructions for some appearance options.
3. Now, you are ready to start LyX. Do so, and notice there are no changes in the appearance. Not to worry -- you need to tell LyX to use your own customized UI file instead of the standard one. The user interface selection is naturally under *Look & Feel->User Interface* in LyX preferences. Choose your new file, restart LyX, and keep your fingers crossed.

More things to do:

- You might also want to assign a keyboard shortcut to your custom commands, and you can do so in LyX preferences, under *Editing->Shortcuts*.

At this point you are probably discouraged enough and decided this is not worth the hassle. I'm tempted to agree with you, and found that a handy opened command line window / Unix shell is far more convenient than messing with UI configuration files.

**Links:**

- [A blog with some handy LyX customization tips.](http://www.thousandmonkeys.com/?cat=5)

Comment: thanks for your help with please sir. I will try your suggestion first ^-^